# PrimeNG table fit in the container

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I have an angular component which shows a map or a primeNG table depending on a variable. This component is prepared to act as a child component and be used inside other components. The map fits on the container it is set, but the table exceeds the height of the container if it has too many rows.

I want to force the table fitting the container, It would be nice if it auto-selects the number of rows per page in the paginator depending on the space in the container, but I would also be fine with some kind of scrollbar.

I have tried the classic scrollable='true', scrollheight and that stuff, but they do not work for me.

Edit: Adding the table code:

```
<div><p-table #dt 
                [value]="listaMapa()" 
                [columns]="mostrarColumnas" 
                
                (sortFunction)="customSort($event)" 
                [customSort]="true"
                
                [paginator]="true"
                [showCurrentPageReport]="true" [rows]="10"

                [scrollable]="true" 
                [scrollHeight]="'100%'"
                
                

                currentPageReportTemplate="{first} - {last} de {totalRecords}" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,25,50]">
                <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
                    <tr>
                       
                        <th [pSortableColumn]="'matricula'">Matrícula
                            <p-sortIcon [field]="'matricula'"></p-sortIcon>
                        </th>
                        <th>Latitud
                            
                        </th>
                        <th >Longitud
                            
                        </th>
                        <th>Ubicación</th>
                        <th [pSortableColumn]="'zona'">Zona
                            <p-sortIcon [field]="'zona'" ></p-sortIcon>
                        </th>
                         <th [pSortableColumn]="'fecha'">Fecha de registro
                            <p-sortIcon [field]="'fecha'" ></p-sortIcon>
                        </th>

                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-posiciones>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{posiciones.matricula}}</td>
                        <td>{{posiciones.latitud}}</td>
                        <td>{{posiciones.longitud}}</td>
                        <td>{{posiciones.descripcion}}</td>
                        <td>{{posiciones.zona}}</td>
                        <td>{{posiciones.fecha}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
            </p-table>
</div>
```

The point is that I want to be able to use this table as a child component and make sure that it will not get bigger than the container component. I have added [scrollable]="true" but it does not work for  [scrollHeight]="'100%'" or  [scrollHeight]="'100hv'" so I have to fix the height of the table in order to make the scroll work. I have also tried style="height: 100%;"but nothing changes.

Comment: Can you perhaps set up a demo on Stackblitz?

Comment: @Shai I have been trying to set up a Stackblitz but it will not work as my app works with multiples webservices to get the data. In case is enough with that I could add my code to the question. I am sorry.

Comment: Try setting the style `height: 100%` on the table. If you have other elements with the table inside the container, you can use flexbox and place `flex-grow: 1` on the table. I can elaborate if need be.

Comment: @Shai I have been playing with the flex and the style this morning but I got nothing. I have added the code in case it may help.

Answer (score 1):

To fit the PrimeNg table into a container, you should set the scrollHeight property to flex rather than 100%, or 100vh.

```
    [scrollable]="true"
    [scrollHeight]="flex"
```